# How to repeat a matrix in dlib?

Tags: c++, matrix, dlib

Is there a fast way in dlib to fill an output matrix with repeated copies of the input matrix?
Something like OpenCv [repeat](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#repeat) function.

Pseudocode as an example:

```
dlib::matrix<double>  input(3, 1), output(3, 3);

input = 3.5,  
        1.2,    
        7.8;

output = repeat(input, row=1, column=3);

output = 3.5,  3.5, 3.5,
         1.2,  1.2, 1.2,
         7.8,  7.8, 7.8;
```

Comment: Isn't that just the [tensor_product](http://dlib.net/dlib/matrix/matrix_utilities_abstract.h.html) of your input matrix with a 1x3 matrix full of ones?

Comment: Yes, That solves the problem for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Botje Please consider adding that as an answer so it can help the future visitors to this question.